# Rails ActiveRecord use join or includes instead of find_by_sql to get attributes of two tables

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The following gets me the results I want but I am trying to figure out if I could have done this with a join or includes instead.

```
@items = Item.find_by_sql("SELECT *
    FROM items_with_metadata
    FULL OUTER JOIN items ON items.id = items_with_metadata.item_id")
```

The result should be that I get all attributes from both tables and the attributes are null wherever the items_with_metadata did not match an item in the items table.
ALSO, I do not have any associations between the two tables, the id of some items just happens to be in both tables

So for example if I have
items table with

```
 id | name | active
------------------
123 |  a   |   0
456 |  b   |   1
```

and items_with_metadata has

```
color | usable | location | item_id
-----------------------------------
 red  |   yes  |   north  |  123
```

the result of the query will be

```
id  | name | active | color | usable | location | item_id
--------------------------------------------------------
123 |  a   |   0    |  red  |   yes  |   north  |  123
456 |  b   |   1    |       |        |          |
```

I was hoping there was a way to do this using ActiveRecord's joins or includes or any other ActiveRecord method that is not find_by_sql

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Item.joins('FULL OUTER JOIN items_with_metadata ON items.id = items_with_metadata.item_id')

EDIT:

You could also use:

```
@items = Item.includes(:items_with_metadata)
```

This will return only Item models, but will also load all relevant ItemWithMetadata models to the memory which will make them available via:

```
@items.first.items_with_metadata
```

The last statement won't cause a DB query, but load the item metadata from the memory.

Comment: This only returns the attributes from items and not the ones from items_with_metadata

Comment: I edited my answer. ActiveRecord refers to Objects rather than SQL tables. The data you need will be in memory, but not represented as a single table with the joins of both tables' columns. When you need the associated metadata, just refer to it via the corresponding method of your Item object.

Comment: This only works if I had an association named items_with_metadata. But as mentioned previously, I don't have any associations between the tables. Its beginning to seem more more like without making any changes to my tables, there is no way to for me to do what I want using ActiveRecord methods and would probably have to use SQL like I'm doing.